# How to make menu to slide form the right side in mobile device using HTML, CSS and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have to make the menu to slide from the right side after clicked on menu bar icon. I have to slide the menu bar icon also. Below code is displayed menu directly after clicked on the menu bar. I have to display smoothly after clicked on Menu. I need to use this on a mobile device. Would you help me in this?

```js
$(function() {
  var menuVisible = false;
  $('#menuBtn').click(function() {
    if (menuVisible) {
      $('#myMenu').css({
        'display': 'none'
      });
      menuVisible = false;
      return;
    }
    $('#myMenu').css({
      'display': 'block'
    });
    menuVisible = true;
  });
  $('#myMenu').click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'display': 'none'
    });
    menuVisible = false;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
}
.menu li {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu-bar {
  display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .menu-bar {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  #myMenu {
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
  }
  .menu ul {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
  }
  .menu ul li {
    float: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .menu li a {
    padding: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-bar">
    <span id="menuBtn"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  </div>
  <ul id="myMenu">
    <li><a href="">home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">about</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">service</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div style="position: relative;top: 50px;">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ut neque dignissim, lobortis nulla sed, tristique urna. Pellentesque placerat, nunc eu feugiat tincidunt, lacus turpis dictum elit, non viverra elit metus at purus. Morbi eleifend
    dui velit, sit amet pretium odio lacinia eget. Nullam mattis massa in nibh laoreet euismod. Phasellus ullamcorper elit quis neque fermentum, at vehicula dolor posuere. Quisque gravida arcu a metus dignissim, vitae convallis ipsum vestibulum. Aliquam
    mollis magna non velit convallis, ut eleifend mauris pharetra. Phasellus ac ipsum pulvinar, dignissim lacus ut, dapibus purus. Integer volutpat ullamcorper magna quis vehicula. Maecenas rhoncus, turpis ac aliquam hendrerit, purus velit pellentesque
    tellus, vitae scelerisque metus leo vestibulum leo. Duis ac vulputate tortor. Aliquam at diam ullamcorper, finibus purus ac, dictum sem. Nulla quis dignissim orci. Donec vel purus eget elit feugiat auctor eget eget odio. Praesent volutpat purus in
    dui aliquam dignissim. Curabitur bibendum lorem id rutrum congue. Nulla urna diam, malesuada ac nibh consequat, auctor egestas ipsum. In non ipsum augue. Maecenas at velit tempus, pellentesque dui non, volutpat tellus. Duis ullamcorper lorem vel blandit
    scelerisque. Etiam venenatis est non urna volutpat, nec commodo neque condimentum. Maecenas sed tortor lacinia, viverra ligula vel, maximus ex. Aenean ut vestibulum lectus. Donec l</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at this , done with simple jQuery

```js
$(function(){
 $('#menuBtn').on('click', function(){
  if( $(this).hasClass('right_margin') ){
   $(this).removeClass('right_margin');
   $('#myMenu').removeClass('active');
  }else {
   $(this).addClass('right_margin');
   $('#myMenu').addClass('active');
  }
  
  
 });
  
});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
.menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 float: right;
}
.menu li {
 float: left;
 margin: 10px;
}
.menu li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #333;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu-bar {
 display: none;
}
 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
.menu-bar {
 display: block;
 float: right;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin: 10px;
 
}
#menuBtn {
 transition-duration:1s;
 -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
 -ms-transition-duration:1s;
 -moz-transition-duration:1s;
}
#myMenu {
 z-index: 999;
 transition-duration:1s;
 -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
 -ms-transition-duration:1s;
 -moz-transition-duration:1s;
}
.menu ul {
 background-color: red;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 right: -300px;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 0px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
 -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
}
.menu ul li {
 float: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 20px;
 text-align: left;
}
.menu li a {
 padding: 20px;
}
.menu .active {
 right:0;
 transition-duration:1s;
 -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
 -ms-transition-duration:1s;
 -moz-transition-duration:1s;
}
.right_margin {
 margin-right:150px;
 transition-duration:1s;
 -webkit-transition-duration:1s;
 -ms-transition-duration:1s;
 -moz-transition-duration:1s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu-bar"> <span id="menuBtn"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span> </div>
  <ul id="myMenu">
    <li><a href="">home</a> </li>
    <li><a href="">about</a> </li>
    <li><a href="">service</a> </li>
    <li><a href="">contact</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div style="width:100%; float:left">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ut neque dignissim, lobortis nulla sed, tristique urna. Pellentesque placerat, nunc eu feugiat tincidunt, lacus turpis dictum elit, non viverra elit metus at purus. Morbi eleifend
    dui velit, sit amet pretium odio lacinia eget. Nullam mattis massa in nibh laoreet euismod. Phasellus ullamcorper elit quis neque fermentum, at vehicula dolor posuere. Quisque gravida arcu a metus dignissim, vitae convallis ipsum vestibulum. Aliquam
    mollis magna non velit convallis, ut eleifend mauris pharetra. Phasellus ac ipsum pulvinar, dignissim lacus ut, dapibus purus. Integer volutpat ullamcorper magna quis vehicula. Maecenas rhoncus, turpis ac aliquam hendrerit, purus velit pellentesque
    tellus, vitae scelerisque metus leo vestibulum leo. Duis ac vulputate tortor. Aliquam at diam ullamcorper, finibus purus ac, dictum sem. Nulla quis dignissim orci. Donec vel purus eget elit feugiat auctor eget eget odio. Praesent volutpat purus in
    dui aliquam dignissim. Curabitur bibendum lorem id rutrum congue. Nulla urna diam, malesuada ac nibh consequat, auctor egestas ipsum. In non ipsum augue. Maecenas at velit tempus, pellentesque dui non, volutpat tellus. Duis ullamcorper lorem vel blandit
    scelerisque. Etiam venenatis est non urna volutpat, nec commodo neque condimentum. Maecenas sed tortor lacinia, viverra ligula vel, maximus ex. Aenean ut vestibulum lectus. Donec l</p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Hybreeder did you check this

Comment: you want to move the menubutton also, thats why i put a class there , both classes are toggling

Comment: `right_margin` added to `menuBtn` `<span id="menuBtn" class="right_margin">` you dont need to add that, it will added only you click the `menuBtn`

Comment: just copy paste this code a simple html page , then inspect on browser , you can understand whats happening

Comment: Yes, it's working for me but it is also forcing the dummy  content

Comment: check the answer ,  i have changed the div style `<div style="width:100%; float:left">` now there is no problem , please accept the answer if its worked for you

Comment: Sure Naila, It's working for me.Thanks for your help. Upvote from my side

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQueryUI slide effect](https://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/). See working example below:

```js
    $(function() {
        var menuBtn = $('#menuBtn'), myMenu = $("#myMenu");
        menuBtn.click(function() {
            if ( $("#myMenu").is(":visible") ) {
                menuBtn.removeClass("right_margin");
                myMenu.toggle("slide", {direction: "right"}, 400);
                
                return;
            }
            menuBtn.addClass("right_margin");
            myMenu.toggle("slide", {direction: "right" }, 500);
        });
        
        myMenu.click(function (){
           menuBtn.trigger("click");
        });
    });
```

```css
    body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .menu ul
    {
     list-style: none;
     float: right;
    }
    .menu li{
     float: left;
     margin: 10px;
    }
    .menu li a{
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #333;
     text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .menu-bar
    {
     display: none;
    }

    .right_margin{
      margin-right: 150px; 
      transition-duration:.5s;
      -webkit-transition-duration:.5s;
      -ms-transition-duration:.5s;
      -moz-transition-duration:.5s;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

     .menu-bar
     {
      display: block;
      float: right;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: 10px;
     }
     #myMenu
     {
      display: none;
          z-index: 999;
     }
     .menu ul {
      background-color: red;
      height: 100%;
      position: fixed; 
         top: 0;
         right: 0;
         bottom: 0;
         padding: 0px;
          -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
    box-shadow:         1px 1px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
     }

     .menu ul li
     {
      float: none;
      border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
      width: 100%; 
      margin: 20px;
      text-align: left;
     }
     .menu li a{
      padding: 20px;
     }


    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menu-bar">
        <span id="menuBtn"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
    <ul id="myMenu">
        <li><a href="">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="">service</a></li>
        <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div style="position: relative;top: 50px;">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque ut neque dignissim, lobortis nulla sed, tristique urna. Pellentesque placerat, nunc eu feugiat tincidunt, lacus turpis dictum elit, non viverra elit metus at purus. Morbi eleifend dui velit, sit amet pretium odio lacinia eget. Nullam mattis massa in nibh laoreet euismod. Phasellus ullamcorper elit quis neque fermentum, at vehicula dolor posuere. Quisque gravida arcu a metus dignissim, vitae convallis ipsum vestibulum. Aliquam mollis magna non velit convallis, ut eleifend mauris pharetra. Phasellus ac ipsum pulvinar, dignissim lacus ut, dapibus purus.

    Integer volutpat ullamcorper magna quis vehicula. Maecenas rhoncus, turpis ac aliquam hendrerit, purus velit pellentesque tellus, vitae scelerisque metus leo vestibulum leo. Duis ac vulputate tortor. Aliquam at diam ullamcorper, finibus purus ac, dictum sem. Nulla quis dignissim orci. Donec vel purus eget elit feugiat auctor eget eget odio. Praesent volutpat purus in dui aliquam dignissim. Curabitur bibendum lorem id rutrum congue. Nulla urna diam, malesuada ac nibh consequat, auctor egestas ipsum. In non ipsum augue. Maecenas at velit tempus, pellentesque dui non, volutpat tellus. Duis ullamcorper lorem vel blandit scelerisque. Etiam venenatis est non urna volutpat, nec commodo neque condimentum. Maecenas sed tortor lacinia, viverra ligula vel, maximus ex. Aenean ut vestibulum lectus.

    Donec l</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Dexterb. My 95% issue got resolved. and 5% is can you assist me to set that Menu bar icon on the menu?. So that if any user clicked on menu bar icon that icon also slide. Right now that menu bar icon displaying behind the menu.

Comment: I have to also display the menu icon bar.Right now that showing behind of menu.

Comment: @Hybreeder  I updated my answer and used @naila's `.right_margin` css class to get the functionality you are looking for. Since @naila's answer is a lot better. It's up to you now what works best for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mr.dexterb. upvote from my side.